# Text is hiding behind background-image

Tags: css, background-image

I want to display text in front of the background-image. But it will always hide my text.
Code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="header"> 
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="container-bg">
  </div>
  <div class="container-content">
    <h1>Test Test Test Test Test Test</h1> 
    <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #ccc
}
p {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ccc
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.container-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
    url(https://i2.wp.com/www.pro-gamer-gear.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/gamer-pc-zusammenstellen.jpg?fit=1170%2C700);
    background-size: cover;
}
.container-content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g700q3qc/3/

Please help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position:relative` here -

```
.container-content {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #ccc
}
p {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ccc
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.container-bg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: -60px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
  background-image: 
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
url(https://i2.wp.com/www.pro-gamer-gear.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/gamer-pc-zusammenstellen.jpg?fit=1170%2C700);
background-size: cover;
}
.container-content {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="container-bg">
  </div>
  <div class="container-content">
<h1>Test Test Test Test Test Test</h1> 
<p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I have came across this same problem, and adding position: relative works.  Could you explain why this works?  I looked here, and it does mention z-index but I'm unsure I fully understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: @mickeysox , the stacking mechanism  works with position properties like relative, absolute and fixed.  `container-content` is static by default.   In this html, `container-content` is placed below `container-bg`. so in this case z-index is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!!

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #ccc
}
p {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ccc
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.container-bg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: -60px;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),
    url(https://i2.wp.com/www.pro-gamer-gear.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/gamer-pc-zusammenstellen.jpg?fit=1170%2C700);
    background-size: cover;
}
.container-content {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="container-bg">
  </div>
  <div class="container-content">
    <h1>Test Test Test Test Test Test</h1> 
    <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```